# Eureka - Custom Cell with on SelectorViewController

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

what's the best way to use a custom cell of a UITableViewController presented with a PushRow?

```
+++ Section() 
    <<< PushRow<Room>() {
        $0.title = "Room"
        $0.value = self.element.room
        $0.displayValueFor = {$0?.name ?? "select Room"}
        $0.cell.height = {60.0}
        }
```

have I to implement a custom SelectorViewController?